# Android open CV

Tags: android

hi I am new to the Android. I am developing one camera application using open CV. In some websites  "opencv not supported by all Android mobiles". can anyone tell "open cv will work in all Android mobiles".
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can learn about open cv from some books which you can get from http://www.filtrlink.com and search for opencv in the search box

Answer (score 3):

No, OpenCV will not work WELL in all android mobiles
The minimal platform supported by OpenCV Java API is Android 2.2 (API 8).

And if you want a full access to OpenCV library you must use native code (C) 
and you'll need an android mobiles with good specifications
for myself I'm using sony xperia p, samsung galaxy S, samsung galaxy gio,samsung galaxy S2 and samsung galaxy note for testing

Only samsung galaxy S2 and samsung galaxy note can run my facedetection smoothly
for another references you can take a look at OpenCV for Android official pages -> http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Comment: You're welcome :)
if you satisfied with my answer
could you please accept it?
thanks :)